# Excel - Check if value exists in a column in another worksheet and return adjacent column

Tags: vba, excel

I have two worksheets:

- EVERYONE
- EVENTBRITE

In `EVERYONE` I have Column A taken by Email addresses. Columns C to Z are full of other data.

In `EVENTBRITE` I have Column A taken by Email addresses. Column B is `Course`

SO what I am looking for is in `EVERYONE`, column B to be populated with the corresponding course

I have tried the following in B2 but I get a #REF error

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,EVENTBRITE!A:A,2,0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,EVENTBRITE!A:B,2,0)
```

Hope this help.